# Problem with `id` field in URL when Editing in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, hidden-field

I am facing issue about `id` field in the regular `http://localhost/bekzcart/admin/users/edit/6` structure.

I have 6 fields for user, all are validated as 'non empty' through model. While editing one user I put one hidden field.

On submitting the form, naturally it gives me error (coming from model) saying 'non empty'. Without entering anything in that field, I hit submit again, now I face the issue.

What happens this time is that 'id' field from the url is now gone, http://localhost/bekzcart/admin/users/edit) and there is a new entry in database (ideally it should update though).

What might be the error?

My Users Controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';

    function admin_edit($id) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        $userLevels = $this->User->Level->find('list', array('fields' => array('LEVEL_ID', 'lEVEL_NAME')));
        $this->set('levels', $userLevels);

        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->User->read();
        } else {
            $this->User->set($this->data);

            if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('USER_LOGIN', 'USER_NAME', 'USER_EMAIL', 'USER_ADDRESS', 'USER_PHONE')))) { 
                $this->data['User']['USER_MODIFIED'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');

                if ($this->User->save($this->data)) { 
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Edit User Success.', true));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something wrong with the query', true));    
                }
            }    
        }                
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $primaryKey = 'USER_ID';

    // Validation in here
    // Association in here
}
```

My related view: admin_edit.ctp

```
$this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden')) // The Hidden Id Not Work
```

Many-many thanks for advance,

regrad

Brian ...

Comment: You can type out three pages of code but have to abbreviate "thanks"? :-S

Comment: Hehe, cheers. In seriousness, though, this is a **lot** of code to sift through. You'll generally find that you get more attention if you boil your question down to a minimal code example that shows your problem without bogging the reader down in unnecessary details of your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `id` must be replaced by the primary key used by the related table, in this case is `USER_ID`

```
$this->Form->input('USER_ID', array('type' => 'hidden'))
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of cake are you using? update to the latest one, `echo $this->Form->input('id');` will automatically be hidden.

And post the full code that generates the form, the output form should be something like this:

> ```
> <form id="AdminUserEditForm" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/admin/users/edit/1" method="post">
> ```

One more suggestion: add 'created' and 'modified' fields to your users table (type datetime). Cake will keep track of these fields for you.

Comment: My cake version is 1.3, allright now I solve the problem. The field `id` must be the primary key used by the table. I change `id` with `USER_ID` and everything is well now. Thanks for your reply